# How do you correctly use private functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, private

I'm new to Python and I'm facing some issues when it comes to private functions. I want to call two of them inside a public method, just for the sake of making the code look clear, but I cannot understand at all what the run-time error shows. Here is the problematic part of the complete code:

```
def __loadVec(self,vec,res):
    for i in range(0,res.getRows()):
        for j in range(0,res.getColumns()):
            vec.append(self.matrix[i][j])
    return

def __savetoMatrix(self,vec,res):
    index = 0
    for i in range(0,res.getRows()):
        for j in range(0,res.getColumns()):
            self.matrix[i][j] = vec[index]
            index += 1
    return

def fmatrixSort(self,res):
    try:
        print "Sorting matrix information..."
        vec = []
        self._matrix.__loadVec(vec,res)
        vec.sort()
        self_matrix.__savetoMatrix(vec,res)
    except TypeError:
        print "TypeError in fmatrixSort"            
    return
```

What I'm trying to do is to completely organize a matrix so as it starts with the lowest value and ends with the highest.

This is the error the program shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MatrixClass.py", line 211, in <module>
    main()
  File "MatrixClass.py", line 203, in main
    mat.fmatrixSort(res)
  File "MatrixClass.py", line 154, in fmatrixSort
    self._matrix.__loadVec(vec,res)
AttributeError: matrix instance has no attribute '_matrix'
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Don't use class-private `__identifiers` in Python. They exist for a completely different reason than private members in Java/C++ and are not a replacement for them.

Comment: your code is borken, what is `self_matrix`; also your problem is not caused because of __methods, but missing self._matrix attribute!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't quite have the concept of `private` functions. It does, however, treat class attributes whose names start with at least two underbars and end with at most one underbar a little specially - it mangles the names to make them slightly harder to access. In this example, you can see that the function `__func2` has had its name mangled. It's still possible to access and call the function - but you have to make a special effort to do it, simply calling `o.func2()` fails:

```
james@bodacious:tmp$cat test.py

class myclass:

    def func1(self):
        print "one"

    def __func2(self):
        print "two"

o = myclass()

print dir(o)

o._myclass__func2()
o.func2()
james@bodacious:tmp$python test.py
['__doc__', '__module__', '_myclass__func2', 'func1']
two
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    o.func2()
AttributeError: myclass instance has no attribute 'func2'
james@bodacious:tmp$
```

So to answer the question you asked:

> How do you correctly use private functions in Python?

The answer is: just like any other function, but you have to be aware of the mangled name.

Moving on to the question you wanted to ask:

```
AttributeError: matrix instance has no attribute '_matrix'
```

This is coming from line 154:

```
self._matrix.__loadVec(vec,res)
```

The error message is telling you that the object called `self` is an instance of class `matrix`; but it has no attribute called `_matrix`. Referring to the `__savetoMatrix` function above, it looks like the attribute is simply called `matrix`- so you need to refer to it as `self.matrix` ("the attribute called `matrix` of the object called `self`).

This The `__savetoMatrix` function references `self.matrix` rather than `self._matrix`.

However, there's a deeper problem here. Reading between the lines, it looks as though this code comes from a class called `matrix`; and instances of the class have an attribute called `matrix`. When you call `self.matrix.__loadVec()`, you're calling the function called `__loadvec()` which is bound to the attribute `matrix` bound to the object called `self`.

Even if this is what you wanted to do, this won't work because of name mangling as outlined above - assuming that the attribute called `matrix` has class `inner_matrix`, you'd have to call the function as `self._matrix._inner_matrix__loadVec()`

I *think* that what you're actually trying to do is call the method called `__loadVec()` defined in class `matrix` though. To do this, you just need to call `self.__loadVec()`. Because it's a call to a function within the same class, you don't even need to worry about the name mangling - these functions are intended to be used inside the class, and the interpreter will handle the mangling for you.

```
james@bodacious:tmp$cat test.py

class myclass:

    def func1(self):
        print "one"

    def __func2(self):
        print "two"

    def func3(self):
        self.__func2()
        print "three"

o = myclass()
print dir(o)
o.func3()
james@bodacious:tmp$python test.py
['__doc__', '__module__', '_myclass__func2', 'func1', 'func3']
two
three
```

Comment: You said "Python doesn't quite have the concept of private functions." and this would be a much better answer if you'd stopped there.

Comment: Disagree; Julian's underlying question had nothing to do with private functions, that was just a distraction that had to be handled so we could get to the real issues.

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed up `self.matrix`, `self._matrix`, and `self_matrix` in several parts of your code. Most likely, you meant `self.matrix` or `self._matrix`, and the others are typos. Also, `fmatrixSort` should probably be calling `__loadVec` and `__savetoMatrix` on `self` instead of what it's currently doing.

Additional notes:

You don't need to `return` at the end of a function if you don't have a value to return. When execution hits the end of a function, the function returns automatically.

`range` can be called in 3 ways:

```
range(stop)
range(start, stop)
range(start, stop, step)
```

If you're going to start the range at 0, just leave out the `start` parameter and call `range` with 1 argument.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize I can do that